# Public html folder moved in tmp folder and nothing is working?

Tags: php, jquery, ftp, ftp-client, public-html

I am in trouble. I was trying to access public_html folder of my site and suddenly that folder has moved in tmp folder by drag and drop or I dont know why? Now my site is not working. And there was so many folder in Public_html . In tmp folder it is showing with 000Public_html000.
All data is there. I have copied public_html folder from tmp in the /root in cpanel. But nothing is working for me. .

Can anybody help me! Please!

Answer (score 0):

**Try to fire that command.**

mv sourceDir destDir

or generate the ticket for restore the server from previous version.

Comment: How? I am new user, neither I knwo about mv sourceDir destDir or genrating the ticket for restore the server from previous version.